# C++ Counting Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, counting

Recently I was dealing with what I am sure is a very common problem, which essentially boils down into the following:

Given a long text, calculate the frequency of each word occurring in the text.

I was able to solve this problem using `std::unordered_map`. This, however, turned quite ugly, as for every word in the text, if that's already been encountered I had to do a find, erase, and then a re-insert into the map with the value incremented.

I realise there are other ways of doing this, such as using a hashing function on top of a vanilla array/vector and increment value there, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of solving this problem, like an STL component, or function. that would have a similar interface to Pythons Counter collections.

I know C++ being C++ I can't really expect such high level concepts to always be implemented for me, but was just wondering if you guys new about anything (or at least your Googling skills are superior to mine) which could make my code a little nicer.

Comment: Why not use `std::unordered_multiset<std::string>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`?

Comment: I was actually using an `unordered_map`. Sorry, typo :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why an `std::unordered_map` (or just `std::map`) would involve much complexity. I'd write the code something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> words;

std::string word;
while (word = getword(input))
   ++words[word];
```

There's no need for any kind of find/erase/reinsert.

In case it's not clear how/why this works: `operator[]` will create an entry for a value if none exists yet in the map. The associated value will be a value-initialized object of the specified type, which will be zero in the case of an `int` (or similar). We then increment that every time we encounter the word.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware the [] operator was overloaded this way, and wasn't really the easiest thing to search for. This definitely solves my problem.

Comment: FYI, this is called Autovivification. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution:

```
std::multiset<std::string> m;
for (auto w: words) m.insert(w);

m.count("some word");
```

The advantage is that you don't have to rely on the 'trick' with `operator[]`, making the code more readable.

**EDIT**: As Kerrek pointed out in the comments, this solution is slower. `multiset` stores all the elements you insert, even if they are deemed equal (they might still differ in some aspect that `operator==` does not check). This causes a significant overhead compared to `unordered_map<std::string, int>`, which only has to store each word once.

(As a side note, processing the complete works of William Shakespeare using the map solution takes about 0.33s on my machine, as opposed to 0.78s for the multiset solution.)

Comment: This is an absurdly horrendous solution :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB Why? If you search for implementations of multisets, a lot of people use mappings to an int anyway, so this is basically the same thing just a bit more high-level. (example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/NBXJ6tAWj48/uzp5nFqjnZAJ )

Comment: Imagine you want to count a histogram of words in several terabytes worth of text streaming in from the network...

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are right, I benchmarked both solutions, and this one has quite some overhead. Added the details to my answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? I explained an alternative solution, which has a worse performance but still provides people having the same problem with some extra info as to *why* this solution is worse (although multisets (mathematically seen) are basically made for usecases like this, just not C++'s version of it)

Comment: `multiset` really is the wrong tool here. It would keep a copy for every occurrence of every string, which is quite unnecessary. You only need to store the count per string, not each string.